# Search not obvious whether for subdomain or all of StackExchange

Tags: discussion, search, feedback

*This is nothing big, and probably applies to most or all of the StackExchange subdomain sites.

When I want to search for example meta.stackexchange.com, the search box is easy enough to see, but in the same row at the left is the StackExchange logo which does make me ponder at first whether it searches meta.stackexchange.com or all StackExchange sites.